# Year missing in citation with biblatex and chicago-authordate style

Tags: citing, texmaker, biber, chicago-style

I am using Texmaker 4.0.2 to compile a document with citations and I need them in the chicago-authordate style.

When I compile the document and look at the pdf, the in-text citations are there, but no year is printed. In other words, I get something like "as stated by *Author*", rather then "as stated by *Author (year)*".

My compiling sequence is : pdflatex, biber, pdflatex.

I am providing a minimum working example below :

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

% Packages                       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ireq.bib}

\begin{document}

As stated by \cite{Audet2006}, the year doesn't print!

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the ireq.bib file contains :

```
@article{Audet2006,
author = {Audet, C and Dennis, J},
doi = {10.1137/040603371},
journal = {SIAM Journal on Optimization},
number = {1},
pages = {188--217},
title = {{Mesh Adaptive Direct Search Algorithms for Constrained Optimization}},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/040603371},
volume = {17},
year = {2006}
}
```

Thanks for any insight you may provide! I'll be glad to add any needed information, I am quite desperate to get this working!

Comment: I get errors: `Toggle 'cms@ordate' undefined`, `Undefined control sequence` about `\postvolpunct` and `Toggle 'cms@doionly' undefined`. My impression is that the last update to `biblatex` broke `authordate-chicago`.

Comment: I tried to use style=authoryear in the preamble and the problem was resolved. It may indeed be a problem with the chicago-authordate option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because when I just ran the MWE, the problem did not persist with a recent version of `biblatex`. Additionally, `biblatex-chicago` is not loaded correctly, it should be `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}`.